# opening a document opens a old version of my app

Tags: xcode, cocoa, document, document-based

I have a `document based application`. 
If i open a saved file via double click on the file then a old version of my program (that I removed from the system) is opened instaed of the newer one. The application is a `stand alone application`.

How can i avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is removed from the system it won't launch. You do in fact have another copy of the app somewhere. Launch services cannot tell te difference between them and may launch either one. 
You need to locate the old version (and any other instances) and at least move it to the trash.